# How to loop over all folders in a given directory and create shortcuts for them in vbs?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I have a batch file that creates a temporary vbs script to create a shortcut but I am getting stuck when trying to insert it in to a for loop that will create a shortcut in a given directory for all folders in that directory.

Here is the vbs script that I am using to make a shortcut:

```
@echo off
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Hello.lnk" >> 
CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
del CreateShortcut.vbs
```

And here is my attempt to insert it into a for loop:

```
FOR /D %r in (dir) do(
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%cd%\%%r.ink" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%cd%\%%r" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
del CreateShortcut.vbs)
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? Have you checked that the created vbs is correct?

Comment: Why would you place a shortcut to every directory within the same container as those directories themselves? It would greatly improve your chances of receiving help if you were to tell us what your real task is, the genuine shortcut you're wanting to create, with the proper file path and name, _(not made up to protect NOTHING AT ALL)_. That's not `For /D` syntax either.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Loop

```
FOR /D %%r (dir) do (
...
)
```

Comment: Incorrect, `%%r` would always hold the value `dir`, perhaps the OP was looking for `For /D %%r In ("dir\*") Do (`